# configure proxy in AWS Synthetics Canary NodeJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

Good morning, I've been trying to configure an AWS Cloudwatch Canary to make a request to a website through a proxy.

I have tried the browser argument options.
Is there any option using AWS Synthetics to make calls through a proxy?
In this Canary I have configured the proxy using 2 environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

This proxy is authenticated with username and password.

I have tried with environment variables, setting the argument in the browser with proxyUrl and with puppeeter's authenticate method.